# empty pom and jar files in maven repository

Tags: maven, maven-3, geonetwork

I'm trying to get geonetwork-opensource up and running on a new machine.
Windows 11, ASUS Amd CPU, fork core-geonetwork from Github to local repo, Java JDK 8 (when try 4.2.x branch ), Java JDK 11 for main (4.4) branch, Maven 3.9.4.

> mvn clean install -DskipTests   is failing

get a bunch of warnings like
[WARNING] The POM for jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

Then errors for missing symbols and classes.  In the .m2 repo, there are a bunch of empty .pom and .jar files that correspond to the warnings. for some reason these are getting put in the repo empty. I can do a web search and find the files with correct content in repos on the web.  When I run this process on my old laptop (also win 11, same config except I7 processor and lots of cruft from years of use) it works-- the repo files have the correct content.

I'm wondering if there's some credential, ssh, or windows security thing that's causing the problem. Other ideas or suggestions?
thanks.

see above. Tried two branches in core-geonetwork repo with different java versions. Elasticsearch install worked after I found the pom content to put in the empty pom in the repo.  There's too many empty poms that gn is looking for to try that. I'm currently trying copying my .m2/repository from the old machine to replace the one on my new machine...

Comment: as I research, it looks like the empty pom and jar files in my repo are coming from modules that have {file name}>osgeo= in the _remote.repositories file.   Now I'm trying to figure out if theres some problem with https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/ (assmuing that's what osgeo= points to....

Comment: The problem should have been fixed already https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo/ticket/2978